# Importing Ruby from C# (Windows)

Tags: c#, ruby, windows, embed, pinvoke

I am trying to create a C# library that "embeds" a Ruby interpreter, using DllImport to execute C-Ruby functions.

```
    public const string RUBY_DLL = @"msvcrt-ruby18";

    [DllImport(RUBY_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void ruby_init();

    // ... Everything in between...

    [DllImport(RUBY_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void ruby_finalize();
```

This works perfectly fine, and I am quite able to import the functions and interact with Ruby, but only if using msvcrt-ruby18.dll, which is obviously outdated. I would like to use msvcrt-ruby240.dll, or even msvcrt-ruby19*.dll, but every attempt I make to do so fails. I created a variant that loads the functions with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress, that way I could use any installed version of Ruby, but everything fails.

When using DllImport, I get the "DllNotFoundException", which seems to indicate a missing dependency of the Ruby dll somewhere. I have ensured that I am building under x86, and using x86 Ruby library, so this is not a BadImageFormat issue. When using the LoadLibrary, I can actually call ruby_init without an error in newer versions, but invoking rb_eval_string fails with anything other than msvcrt-ruby18.dll.

I am quite familiar with using P/Invoke, and am not asking "how" to link to them. I AM quite green when it comes to actually writing C code, or understanding exactly the the differences in builds of the msvcrt-ruby***.dll, static libraries, etc.

After extensive Google research, I cannot find one single example that links C# and Ruby that uses anything newer than msvcrt-ruby18.dll, and was hoping to gain some insight as to how I can and what I have to do. I am not opposed to compiling Ruby myself if that is required, but would really appreciate any tips on that if it is required, and what I would have to edit, etc.

**EDIT:** 
Here's what I am doing.

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
public class RubyHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    public RubyHandle(string rubyDllPath) : base(true)
    {
        SetHandle(LoadLibrary(rubyDllPath));
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public override bool IsInvalid
    {
        get => handle == IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return FreeLibrary(handle);
    }

    public static implicit operator IntPtr(RubyHandle rubyHandle)
    {
        return rubyHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
    }
}
```

And to bind the functions...

```
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static class Ruby
{
    public const string RUBY_DLL = @"C:\Ruby24\bin\msvcrt-ruby240.dll";

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    private static RubyHandle _rubyLib;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void VoidArgs0();

    private static VoidArgs0 _ruby_init;
    private static VoidArgs0 _ruby_finalize;
    private static VoidArgs0 _ruby_show_version;
    private static VoidArgs0 _ruby_show_copyright;

    public static void Initialize(string rubyDllPath = null)
    {
        _rubyLib = new RubyHandle(rubyDllPath ?? RUBY_DLL);
        ImportFunctions();
        _ruby_init.Invoke();
    }

    private static void ImportFunctions()
    {
        _ruby_init = (VoidArgs0) ImportFunction<VoidArgs0>("ruby_init");
        _ruby_finalize = (VoidArgs0) ImportFunction<VoidArgs0>("ruby_finalize");
        _ruby_show_version = (VoidArgs0) ImportFunction<VoidArgs0>("ruby_show_version");
        _ruby_show_copyright = (VoidArgs0) ImportFunction<VoidArgs0>("ruby_show_copyright");
    }

    private static object ImportFunction<T>(string functionName) 
    {
        var ptr = GetProcAddress(_rubyLib, functionName);
        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(T));
    }

    public static void Release()
    {
        _ruby_finalize.Invoke();
        _rubyLib.Dispose();
    }

    public static void ShowVersion()
    {
        _ruby_show_version.Invoke();
    }
}
```

The error occurs right in the beginning, before it even gets started on the call to "LoadLibrary", I get the "Specified module was not found" error. I have also made sure that both "C:\Ruby24\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls" and "C:\Ruby24\bin" are included in PATH.

I am beating my head against a wall. I see no reason why this does not work...

Comment: The msvcrt-ruby240.dll is indeed linked statically (you can find that with de Depends or Dumpbin tools) with libgmp-10.dll. I reproduce your problem on a fresh install, but if I add C:\Ruby24\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls to the PATH now it works, are you sure you restarted your environment so the new PATH is taken into account? PS: I used sysinternals' Procmon tool to find the missing dll.

Comment: PS: also, you should use unicode versions of the LoadLibrary API, in case ruby has been installed it in a path that requires unicode.

Comment: I did indeed add the Unicode versions in the final cut, and not restarting very well may have been my problem, as I did fail to do that. In the end, I find adding the path via AddDllDirectory the cleaner solution, but it sure didn't do me any favors debugging my problem by not restarting after changing adding to PATH. :facepalm:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so finally figured this out, will post the answer here for anyone else who may stumble into a similar problem.

I ended up manually adding the directories for Ruby's dependencies via "AddDllDirectory":

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AddDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
```

And then using "LoadLibraryEx" opposed to "LoadLibrary", and specifying the "LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS" flag.

```
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hReservedNull, LoadLibraryFlags dwFlags);

    [System.Flags]
    enum LoadLibraryFlags : uint
    {     
        DontResolveDllReferences = 0x00000001,
        LoadIgnoreCodeAuthzLevel = 0x00000010,
        LoadLibraryAsDatafile = 0x00000002,
        LoadLibraryAsDatafileExclusive = 0x00000040,
        LoadLibraryAsImageResource = 0x00000020,
        LoadLibrarySearchApplicationDir = 0x00000200,
        LoadLibrarySearchDefaultDirs = 0x00001000,
        LoadLibrarySearchDllLoadDir = 0x00000100,
        LoadLibrarySearchSystem32 = 0x00000800,
        LoadLibrarySearchUserDirs = 0x00000400,
        LoadWithAlteredSearchPath = 0x00000008
    }
```

And then...

```
    public static void Initialize(string rubyDllPath = null)
    {
        AddDllDirectory(@"C:\Ruby24\bin");
        AddDllDirectory(@"C:\Ruby24\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls");

        _rubyLib = new RubyHandle(rubyDllPath ?? RUBY_DLL);
        ImportFunctions();
        _ruby_init.Invoke();
    }
```

Obviously the final product will do this dynamically, but this way successfully loads the library.